# Program to create a number of threads based on user input not working (cin)?

Tags: c++, multithreading

My apologies if this question looks simple. I'm still learning about threads. I already tried searching for a solution to this on here but didn't find any.

I'm trying to get my program to create a number of threads based on user input (ex: "cin >> 5" will create 5 threads) but it says the "i" in "threads myThreads[ i ]" needs to be a constant value. The code is below:

```
void exec(int n)
{
    cout << "Thread " << n << endl;
}


int main()
{
    int numThreads = 0;

    // create threads
    cin >> numThreads;
    thread myThreads[numThreads]; // this part says myThreads "must be a constant value"

    for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
    {      
        myThreads[i] = thread(exec, i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
    {
        myThreads[i].join();
    }

    cout << "Done!" << endl;
}
```

Any ideas as to how that section can be fixed? I've tried a few different ways but they haven't worked so far. Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried using `std::vector`? (e.g., `std::vector<thread> myThreads(numThreads);`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no problem with multithreading. The problem is static array that you using as dynamic array.

Try something like this:

```
thread* myThreads = new thread[numThreads];
```

More about dynamic memory in C++:
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/

**UPD By James Adkison:**
Do not forget to `delete[]` your array to avoid memory leaking.

Comment: The is `C++` why not recommend using `std::vector`? It's usually a good idea to not deal directly with dynamic memory allocation (e.g., use `std::unique_ptr` and `std::make_shared`).

Comment: It working now. Thank you very much. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @G_Man Make sure you're aware that this code is not exception safe and will leak resources if `delete[]` is not performed.

Comment: @James Adkison Oh okay. Thank you very much.